# Como permitir apenas um intervalo de números?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu estou fazendo um código de registro de número de notas de alunos, então quero que o usuário coloque um número entre um intervalo de 1 a 10, **MAS** também quero que os intervalos sejam em **float**(ou seja: 0.1,0.2... 9.8,9.9,10.0).

```
nota_1 = float(input("Digite a primeira nota de " + str(aluno_1) + ": "))
mat_aluno_nota [1][0] = nota_1
while nota_1 not in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10):
    print("Digite um número entre 0 a 10")
```

Tem alguma maneira de eu fazer mais rápido sem ser colocando todos de um em um?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```
while True:
    nota_1 = input("Digite a primeira nota de " + str(aluno_1) + ": ")
    try:
        nota_1 = float(nota_1)
    except Exception as err:
        print("Valor deve ser númerico")
    else:
        if 0 <= nota_1 <= 10:
            mat_aluno_nota [1][0] = nota_1
            break
        print("Valor deve estar entre 0 e 10")
```